# User cancelled the dialog

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, google-fit

I am getting this error **(User cancelled the dialog)** when I try the simple code as the example in the Ionic Framework.

```
this.health.isAvailable()
.then((available:boolean) => {
  console.log(available);
  this.health.requestAuthorization([
    'distance', 'nutrition',  //read and write permissions
    {
      read: ['steps'],       //read only permission
      write: ['height', 'weight']  //write only permission
    }
  ])
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
})
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: when you run the code it simply console this error? It doesn't show a dialog?

Comment: @GabrielBarreto yes, only this message in console log. "User cancelled the dialog"

Comment: @RafaelRN I am trying to see whether I can read data from Fitness History of Google Fit, using IONIC. Do you have any references for this?

Comment: @Lijo the only documentation i know about is the [Ionic Native - Health](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/health/) and the github page of the plugin [Github page of project](https://github.com/dariosalvi78/cordova-plugin-health), but this documentation is not enough :(

Answer (score 3):

This problem is listed in the [plugin's documentation](https://github.com/dariosalvi78/cordova-plugin-health#android-quirks) with all the data needed.

But in case it gets lost in the sands of time, here's the excerpt.

It will try to get authorization from the Google fitness APIs. It is necessary that the app's package name and the signing key are registered in the Google API console. (see [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-api-key)).

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers have been correct and headed me in the right direction to finally pinout the issue:

- **SHA-1 certificate fingerprint** must be associated with the OAuth 2.0 client ID in the Fitness API console, and ...
- If Google Play has **App signing certificate** enabled, then you MUST use SHA-1 certificate fingerprint of this certificate, instead of the *Upload certificate*

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with these threads([1](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/125) and [2](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/915)). You might experience this issue due to key hashes issue on Android. Probably same is observed in iOS version. Also based from this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-googleplus), make sure that your package name (i.e. the app ID) is what you want it to be. Use this package name when setting up iOS and Android. If you don't, you will likely get a 12501, 'user cancelled' error despite never cancelling the log in process.